# Facebook - AccessTokenTracker is not tracking the permission changes

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-access-token, android-facebook, facebook-permissions

I am using the AccessTokenTracker to keep my app aware of any permission changes happening in online say for example via a laptop.

Secanario : The app logs into my FB and gains access to "publish_actions
". If the user is removing the "publish_actions" permission using his laptop or any other device then  my AccessTokenTracker is not getting updated with the latest set of permissions. Hence the code always reaches

```
System.out.println("FB already has publish_actions");
```

### Question

If I am going to update the permissions for  my app in other device will it be updated in the accessTokenTracker ? if so why it is not getting updated in my case ?

### code

```
private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
private AccessToken currentAccessToken;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    // App code
                    System.out.println("FacebookCallback : Success");
                    fbShareNow();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // App code
                    System.out.println("FacebookCallback : Cancel");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    // App code
                    System.out.println("FacebookCallback : Erroe");
                }
            });
    accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken newAccessToken) {
            currentAccessToken=newAccessToken;
        }
    };

    currentAccessToken =  AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
}


@Override
public void facebookShare(String msg) {
    if (currentAccessToken != null) {
        System.out.println("FB already logged in");
        if(currentAccessToken.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions")){
            System.out.println("FB already has publish_actions");
            fbShareNow();
        } else{
            System.out.println("FB has no publish_actions");
        }

    }else {
        System.out.println("FB not logged in");
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
    }
}
```

Comment: You could maybe consider using `refreshCurrentAccessTokenAsync()`? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/AccessToken/